# inserting image in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert an image from a userform to the excel sheet, but if a picture is not selected when I press the submit button on the form it says run-time error '424': object required. How can I solve this problem?
The following is for the browse button.

```
Private Sub browse_Click()
Dim pic As Variant
pic = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With pic

    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .ButtonName = "Submit"
    .Title = "Select an image file"
    .Filters.Add "Image", "*.gif;*.jpg;*.jpeg", 1
    If .Show = -1 Then



            Me.filepath.Text = .SelectedItems(1)
            Me.picpreview.PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeClip
            Me.picpreview.Picture = LoadPicture(.SelectedItems(1))


    Else


    End If

    If pic = False Then Exit Sub

End With




End Sub
```

And the following is the code assigning the image to the specific cell.

```
Cells(emptyrow, 10).Select
With xlApp.ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(picname)   'it is this line the debugger always points to when I submit the form without a picture
    With .ShapeRange
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Height = 150
    End With
    .Left = xlApp.ActiveSheet.Cells(emptyrow, 10).Left
    .Top = xlApp.ActiveSheet.Cells(emptyrow, 10).Top
    .Placement = 1
    .PrintObject = True
End With
```

Comment: check the selected items count before doing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for the picture userform and insertion, the main alteration is that we `Dim` the `Office.FileDialog` for the Window Picker and separate the choosing the picture and setting, instead of using the picture object we simply use the path. You'll need to adjust the _Click names.

```
Public PicPath As String 'this is where we'll store the picture path

Private Sub Browse_Click() 'getting the picture path

Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fDialog

    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .ButtonName = "Submit"
    .Title = "Select an image file"
    .Filters.Add "Image", "*.gif;*.jpg;*.jpeg", 1

    If .Show = -1 Then
        PicPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        'getting picture full path to use when submit click
    End If

    If PicPath = "" Then Unload Me

End With

End Sub

Private Sub Submit_Click()'setting picture in active cell

    If Not PicPath = "" Then
        CellAddress = ActiveCell.Address
        With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PicPath)
            With .ShapeRange
                .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                .Height = 150
            End With
            .Left = ActiveSheet.Range(CellAddress).Left
            .Top = ActiveSheet.Range(CellAddress).Top
            .Placement = 1
            .PrintObject = True
        End With
        picselectedbool = True
    Else
        msgbox ("Please select a picture")
    End If

    If picselectedbool Then
        Unload Me
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! The code does work when I put it into the submit button, however, now it has changed to a situation that even when I haven't select a picture after I clicked submit there is a picture automatically appears. Could it be solved using on error statements ?

Comment: Hi, I thought your goal was to insert the picture in the excel sheet, mb. Could you tell me exactly what you expect the picture insert to behave (like is something supposed to happen between opening the pic and inserting it?) because I think  I misinterpreted it. @白羽ルカ

Comment: What I expected is that I can choose a picture through a userform and once I pressed the submit button on the userform then it would automatically insert the picture to the destination cell I wanted it to be. Sorry for the confusion. @Miguel_Ryu

Comment: Just updated the answer, hope it works like you want it to. btw sorry for the late reply but work called ^^. @白羽ルカ

Comment: Good that it works as you want it to. Please use the correct symbol to accept the answer :). And good luck.